# How to use UIImagePicker with custom cell with a button and the UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to objective c and iOS. The problem is simple that the image that is picked by `UIImagePicker` is assigned to custom cells image view, i have 3 sections with 5 rows with the same button and `UIImageView`. whenever i picked a image on row 3 it displays on all 3 sections row 3. I'm really fed up please can someone please help me with this.
here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   imgArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [imgArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
   [imgArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
   [imgArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
   [imgArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
   [imgArr addObject:[[UIImage alloc]init]];
   [_myTableView reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return imgArr.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 3;
}

- (nullable NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section==0){
      return @"Section 1";
    }else if (section==1){
      return @"Section 2";
    }else{
      return @"Section 3";
    }   
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *myArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    cell.mvc=self;
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(slctImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    index=(indexPath.section * 1000) + indexPath.row;
    section=index%1000;
    NSLog(@"Button Tag is %ld",(long)index);
    cell.imageVw.image=[imgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return  cell;

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    UIImage *pic=[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"image is %@",pic);
    img=pic;
    [imgArr replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:img];

    picker.delegate=self;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [_myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using indexpath.row to get the image for particular cell view but the issue would be indexpath.row =0/1/2 for each section.

Hence every section's first,second or third image would show the image as img[indexPath.row] would return the same image.

You need to check the section using indexPath.section and assign the image accordingly.

Either you can maintain three different array for different sections.
If you want to make it dynamic. 
You need to create your data structure in a way that it accommodates.

Comment: but i need to do this with using only one array can i do it with this type

Comment: now i've got the both indexPath.row and indexPath.section                [imgArr replaceObjectAtIndex:section withObject:img];                                   i want my this array to be array of array replacing the object at indexPath .row for every row and column with the help of only single array is it possible?

Comment: Yes the other way of doing it is.  Creating a proper model for such data source.

Comment: can you please help me i'm so much confused because it is so confusing and i'm new to programming.

Comment: Giving you direct answers won't enhance your skills.. Please refer this link to understand. 

https://medium.com/ios-objective-creation/lesson-2-creating-custom-classes-in-objective-c-17f760ce9732

post this you can create a model which has two properties like section name and images (images again would be an array of images inside the model class definition as you have mentioned make the count 5).
Then in your view controller you can create an array of those model class objects with count 3. 
You face issues after thing..Please comment your here will help you ahead.

Comment: this link is about the classes there is nothing that help me with using array

Comment: did you understand creating custom classes.. its about creating model. once your model is ready .you can tweek it to your requirements.